# AnyLogic Fluid Library Action On Above / Below

Tags: anylogic

When activating the Action on Above for a tank from the Fluid Library, I am unable to change the units to anything other than cubic meters, irrespective of the settings for Capacity and Initial amount. Is this a bug or am I missing a setting?

To reproduce simply drag a tank, check the Action on above checkbox and try to change the units

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just noticed that if you don't put any value on the amount field, you can't change the units, but if you put a value in there, it let you put the units...

So even though it's a bug, you don't need to care about the bug